# power spectral density shows no activity

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the Power Spectral Density between two conditions recorded over multiple trials with 4 EEG electrodes. To do this I am computing trial-wise averages of spectra by:

1. Apply hanning window to a trial
2. Compute fft
3. Take absolute  value squared for power
4. Average over all trials

I have one particular data set that I am analyzing that shows no activity (both baseline and task data are exactly the same/overlapped in figure) and was hoping someone might be able to point me in a direction to figure out why the data appears as it does in this figure: [PSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ountS.jpg). The raw data looks like a quality EEG recording.

Comment: maybe, too short length of trial?

Comment: Each trial is 5 minutes long. I believe that should be sufficient?

Comment: Could you provide raw data and your matlab code?

Comment: @김갑수. My apologies, but I am very new here and am unsure how to share the raw data

Comment: I guess energy of DC component is too strong, so that interesting frequency(maybe, low frequency) is merged under energy leakage of DC component.